# Pass context to navigator push to access inherited widget data

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to access data from an inherited widget placed under the `MaterialApp` in my tree from a `MaterialPageRoute`.

When I try to access the data from this route `UserModel.of(context).data` it say it's `null`

I get that this is because the `UserModel` provider should be placed above the whole `MaterialApp` for it to share the context but it's impossible in my case.

I therefore tried to pass the context from the navigator builder in hope it would give me access to it:

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => SettingsScreen(
                appContext: context)),
   );
}
```

and then in `SettingScreen`

```
UserModel.of(appContext).data
```

But it didn't work either...

Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: Why would you even want to do it? However your build method in SettingsScreen provides you a context.

Comment: Same issue for me. I want to be able to access the the inherited widgets data in a dynamic route.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare a constructor of `SettingsScreen` and pass your data in constructor. :)